# Can't get global variable from other JS file in main JS file with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm learning Webpack and like the idea a lot, but I just don't get this issue I have. I have an app.js file, which has two `require`'s (./logger and ./includes/functions). The app.js looks like this:

```
require('./logger');
require('./includes/functions');

document.write( welcomeTitle );
```

`welcomeTitle` is the variable declared in `./includes/functions`:

```
var welcomeTitle = "Hello World!";
```

But I get the following error when I run this: `bundle.js:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: welcomeTitle is not defined(…)`. The bundle.js file references to the `welcomeTitle` variable before it's required:

```
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    __webpack_require__(1);
    __webpack_require__(2);

    document.write( welcomeTitle );

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    console.log('logger.js is now loaded...');

/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    var welcomeTitle = "Hello World!";
```

Why can't I access the `welcomeTitle` variable if I'm requiring functions.js, where this variable is declared?

Comment: You're `var` welcomeTitle needs to be exported so that it's accessible. Have you looked here http://requirejs.org ?

Comment: No way to do it without Require JS? The whole point of `require` is to get functions/methods and variables etc. from that file right? Isn't there a simpler way to achieve that?

Comment: It's pretty simple - in somefile.js  `function someFn() {} module.exports = someFn` and then in main.js `var someFn = require('./somefile');` You *could* make it a global `var` `window.welcomeTitle = 'something';` but if you're using `require` be consistent and stick with that paradigm.

Comment: @ForeignObject Thank you very much for the help, but I'm a beginner with Webpack, so could you maybe explain where I should put that code and how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `module.exports` to the bottom of your functions file `./includes/functions.js` and set `welcomeTitle` as a property on exports`.

```
var welcomeTitle = 'Hello World';

module.exports.welcomeTitle = welcomeTitle;
```

Then in the file that you want to access `welcomeTitle` in do:

```
var functions = require('./includes/functions');
var welcomeTitle = functions.welcomeTitle;
```

Comment: Great! But do I have to do module.exports for every function and variable I want to access in the main JS file? No way to just export all of them?

Comment: Yes, you can export one function like `module.exports = someFn` but if you want to export multiple `vars`, `functions`, etc then `module.exports = {someVar: 1, someOtherFn: function() {} }` ...there may be better ways that I am unaware of, however, it's best to just export what you need to be accessible.